# I can't get ng-view to work properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been trying for months to figure out what I'm doing wrong with my routes in angular. Could someone take a quick look at this plunk and tell me why ng-view isn't working? $scope.name doesn't display properly and ng-view doesn't seem to be working. http://plnkr.co/edit/7vtgxmvqI0eiDALIW7G8

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('blog', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('about.html', {
        templateURL: "about.html",
        controller: 'AboutController'
    })     
});

app.controller('AboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "marcus";
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="blog">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="about.html">Notes</a>

    <h1>Click the Link ^</h1>
    <h2>{{2+2}}</h2>

    <div ng-view>

      <p>ng-view should be loading data from about.html right here but it's not working</p>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

about.html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>

    <h2>{{name}}</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The demo in plunkr is working just fine.

Comment: Same here - works fine. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Only thing that doesn't work is that I can go directly to dashboard, bypassing the login.
Since you didn't talk about that: everything looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in index.html change the href as follows:

```
<a href="#/about.html">Notes</a>
```

also in script.js:

```
$routeProvider.when('/about.html', {
    templateUrl: "about.html",
    controller: 'AboutController'
  })
```

these changes made your code working for me.
Up to my knowledge the problem lies in routing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Question

Use the preview mode then you see the title in the tab of the page `Plunker - Angular Login App`. http://embed.plnkr.co/ZVVArcJlb8QeGUaFNgBu/preview

2. Question

Also Javascript is a case sensitive language.

Use template*Url* instead of template*URL*:

```
templateUrl: "about.html",
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/9c5JKpxRnskBY6EegFGF?p=preview

*I use Angular 1.4.6 for testing*

Comment: So my mistake was that I was using templateURL instead of templateUrl, or was it that I was using angular 1.2.2?

Comment: The problem was the template*URL*. You can change Angular version back to 1.2.2 and it will probably still work. I was just using the latest version to prevent hunting for bugs already solved.